# Access SQL error-message "database does not recognize as a valid field" - NOT Crosstab

Tags: ms-access

I am receiving the following error: "The Microsoft Access database does not recognize '[ASX Code]' as a valid field name or expression."

Here is the code that throws the error:

```
QUICK_RATIO_CHART_SQL = "SELECT [Quick Ratio] FROM [RATIO ANALYSIS] WHERE [ASX Code] like '" & ASXCODE & "';"
Me.QUICK_RATIO_CHART.RowSource = QUICK_RATIO_CHART_SQL
```

'RATIO ANALYSIS' is a table that contains a field 'ASX Code'.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks
Lee

Comment: Try using: `.. WHERE [RATIO ANALYSIS].[ASX Code] Like ..`

Answer (score 0):

Not *the* answer, but a method to help you getting it right:

- add `debug.print QUICK_RATIO_CHART_SQL` after the line `QUICK_RATIO_CHART_SQL=...`
- run the proc until the `debug.print` is executed
- paste the printed statement in a new view (in SQL view)
- switch to design view and execute
- you should then have a clear view of the error

That how I'd proceed when my eyes pop out my head, like it may happen sometimes.

---

You can also try to *qualify* everything, using an Alias:

```
QUICK_RATIO_CHART_SQL = "SELECT r.[Quick Ratio] FROM [RATIO ANALYSIS] r WHERE r.[ASX Code] like '" & ASXCODE & "';"
```

---

As a last option, use a saved with a criteria pointing to the form control (`formName!controlName`). This way you can test the query without VBA, as long as the form is open.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the SQL query runs perfectly like that. No clearer

Comment: @LMORSE see edit.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution through trial and error. When I had originally inserted the graph, under Chart Settings \ Legend I had ticked [ASX Code]. Changing this to None resolved the error message.